# Get executable Java program from eclipe

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

My intention is to test a small program like

```
public class World
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Foobar World");
    }
}
```

to execute on terminal. I used the well explained documentation in stackoverflow - **How do I build a Java project in Eclipse?**. But when executing the World.jar....

```
$ java World
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: World
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: World
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    Could not find the main class: World. Program will exit.
```

Is the class path causing this error ? I thought eclipse arranges all this for me.... The execution should be all right as

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Foo Foo 1254 Mar 17 19:40 World.jar
```

What do I miss and once it works can I just copy the file to another PC with the same operation system without setting up any class path?

Comment: Are you trying to export your project as an executable jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run a `.jar` file as `java -jar World.jar`. Also, your `.jar` file needs a file in it, `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` with a `Main-Class:` header telling Java what class inside that `.jar` to execute.

Eclipse *can* package your code appopriately and generate this header, but it won't do this by default. You need to poke around in its JAR settings, under `File > Export > Java > Jar`. (According to [this FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_executable_JAR_file_for_a_stand-alone_SWT_program?), which might be outdated.) There might also be a way to tell Eclipse to generate such a JAR automatically on build.

Also remember that this won't be sufficient when using third-party libraries. No idea if Eclipse has anything for this. You'll either have to set up the `Class-Path:` manifest entry, or it might be more convenient to use [Maven's shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) or a standalone tool like [Jar Jar Links](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/).

Comment: I just looked into the World.jar and there is the folder META-INF with the file MANIFEST.MF and the World.java. The MANIFEST.MF includes the following information: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Sealed: true
Main-Class: World

Comment: @Fendrix Then it should just be necessary to run it with `java -jar World.jar`

Comment: then I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: World : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Comment: @Fendrix That's obviously a different error then. Google for it. I'm guessing you have Eclipse set to use JDK 7 but you only have JRE 6 installed globally.

Comment: that was my stupid mistake ... just one question why isn't it enough to just write java World.jar

Comment: @Fendrix Uhh... Because? That's really for whoever came up with the idea to answer. My guess is because then it's ambiguous whether you want to execute the archive `World.jar` or the class `jar.class` in the package `World`, and it's not up to the `java` launcher to make the choice for you, or to be in any way clever. (I.e. convenient.)